# Tailwind CSS grid direction

Tags: next.js, grid, tailwind-css

this grid, output like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I want to adjust the grid on parent Div to output like this:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

(note there might be much more elements, not just 9)

```
<div className="grid h-full grid-cols-3 gap-2">
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              1
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              2
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              3
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              4
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              5
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              6
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              7
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              8
            </button>
            <button className="px-1 py-1 text-white bg-pink-400 rounded h-[50px] min-h-[50px]">
              9
            </button>
          </div>
```

Comment: It worked with this method, upto 6 rows:

<div className="grid h-full grid-flow-col grid-rows-6 gap-1">

Answer (score 1):

So the two things you need are `grid-rows-3` and `grid-flow-col` since you are inverting the x and y directions of the grid.

Here's your updated code:

```
<div class="grid h-full w-full grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-2">
  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">1</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">2</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">3</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">4</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">5</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">6</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">7</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">8</button>

  <button class="h-[50px] min-h-[50px] rounded bg-pink-400 px-1 py-1 text-white">9</button>
</div>
```

I have also made a working demo on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/b0qoNVdzW2).

Cheers!